# Radial distance?

Tags: variance

I'm looking at some code that calls $$\sqrt{(\sigma_x^2)^2+(\sigma_y^2)^2+(\sigma_z^2)^2}$$ the "radial distance", where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation. What is the significance of this measure?

Comment: Are you sure about the double squares ? A standard deviation can be interpreted as a [gyroscopic radius](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/Variance_inertia.html), but because of the double squares this does not look like a standard deviation.

Comment: Yes, the values are taken from a covariance matrix, then squared and square-rooted.

Comment: why would you need a code for computing the square root of the sum of three quantities?

Comment: @Xi'an that is my question. I found the code in a program i am working on, and i don't know why this formula is being used.

Comment: The formula looks like an erroneous implementation of a $\chi$ variate, but it's impossible to tell without the context.  At this point people can attest that it's (a) not a distance (in terms of the original variables, anyway) and (b) highly unusual in statistics.  To get better answers than that it's likely you would need to supply additional information about what the code is trying to do.

Comment: @whuber the random vector being considered is spatial position in cartesian coordinates. This formula is tested against a constant to try to determine if the position estimate is "good enough" or not.

Comment: Then almost surely one set of squares needs to be removed from the expression. Exactly what test is being performed?

Comment: @whuber i can't see any other information that looks relevant enough to include. That formula is just called the "radial distance", and if it's less than 10, then the estimate is considered good enough. I guess i can say that the position estimate is obtained by least squares.

Comment: It's a standard deviation of the sum of independent r.v.s: $\sqrt{Var[x+y+z]}$

Comment: Less than $10$ *what*? The units of measurement matter, because when you multiply the underlying units by $\lambda$, this statistic will be multiplied by $\lambda^2$. (It's not a distance: if anything, it's an *area*!) The reference to a least squares estimate makes this test even more suspicious. You are systematically convincing me that this code is erroneous on several levels!

Comment: @Whuber Erroneous was my initial suspicion. i just wanted a second opinion. I'll consider that suspicion confirmed :)

Comment: @Aksakal what does r.v.s stand for?

Comment: @Jeff, r.v.=random variable. Also, I must retract my comment, you have $\sigma_x^4$ in your equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some documentation for our software referring to the Mean Radial Spherical Error. I think this is probably what was intended in the code. The MRSE is $$r = \sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2 + \sigma_z^2}$$ meaning there is a 61% probability of being within a sphere of radius $r$. This is often used in GPS or radar positioning systems.

Comment: As it stands this just looks like you found a term for a calculation, so it doesn't explain why that matters. This seems like a reasonable comment, but does it really count as an answer to the question? Could you expand on what you found at all? Where did you find it, and what did it say about it?

Comment: @Glen_b For clarification, Mean Radial Spherical Error is not the calculation above. If you don't know what that is, then i could see why you wouldn't know why it matters. I will expand the answer.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Expansion/clarification will likely make this into a useful answer. If you're able to mention some source or reference that will also assist.